# Pasting shape path from file with different grid setting results in pasting previous grid

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, pixel-grid

I am attempting to paste a shape path from an SVG with an SVG file with different grid settings into an another illustrator ai file.

When I do this, I get a copy of the grid from the old file along with my shape path.

I also can't change the settings of the grid path on the svg file.

It also seems to happen when I create or duplicate a layer.

**Here is the initial grid:**
[image: This is the first grid]

**Here is the grid after pasting the new shape path:**
[image: This is the second grid]

Answer (score 1):

The pixel grid starts showing up at a high zoom level. If the grid layout is not divided properly, it will align to subpixels.